# Calculate difference of two layers

Tags: python, theano, keras

I want to merge two keras layers such that the merged layer has the difference of the two layers. For example if layer1 output is [0,1,2] and layer2 output is [1,2,3] the merged layer should be [-1,-1,-1]. I tried using the following

```
from keras.layers import Input, merge
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

input_a = np.reshape([1, 2, 3], (1, 1, 3))
input_b = np.reshape([4, 5, 6], (1, 1, 3))

a = Input(shape=(1, 3))
b = Input(shape=(1, 3))


diff = merge([a, b], mode=lambda x, y: x - y)

diff_model = Model(input=[a, b], output=diff)

print(diff_model.predict([input_a, input_b]))
```

which resulted in the following error,

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1464, in merge                │    self.add_inbound_node(layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    name=name)                                                                                               │  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topolog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1123, in __init__             │y.py", line 543, in add_inbound_node
    self.add_inbound_node(layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)                                              │    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_ind
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 543, in add_inbound_node      │ices)
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)                                     │  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topolog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 153, in create_node           │y.py", line 155, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors, mask=input_masks))                           │    output_shapes = to_list(outbound_layer.get_output_shape_for(inp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1200, in call                 │ut_shapes))
    return self.mode(inputs, **arguments)                                                                    │  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topolog
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I perform the merge operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to merge the layers in the above way using,

```
diff = merge([a, b], mode=lambda (x, y): x - y, output_shape=(3,))
```